# Where is stored the int value of a int instance in Python?

Tags: python, attributes, integer

The `int` type in python offers two attributes named `numerator` and `real` that have the same content as `__int__()`.

As all of these 3 values returns the same internal attribute, I guess `real` is a property like:

```
@property
def real(self):
   return self.__int
```

However I cannot find this hidden property dir `dir` or either `a = int(); a._int__<tab>` in IPython.

So I looked at the [source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/intobject.c) and found this:

```
static PyGetSetDef int_getset[] = {
    {"real",
     (getter)int_int, (setter)NULL,
     "the real part of a complex number",
     NULL},
    {"imag",
     (getter)int_get0, (setter)NULL,
     "the imaginary part of a complex number",
     NULL},
    {"numerator",
     (getter)int_int, (setter)NULL,
     "the numerator of a rational number in lowest terms",
     NULL},
    {"denominator",
     (getter)int_get1, (setter)NULL,
     "the denominator of a rational number in lowest terms",
     NULL},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

And this:

```
static PyObject *
int_int(PyIntObject *v)
{
    if (PyInt_CheckExact(v))
        Py_INCREF(v);
    else
        v = (PyIntObject *)PyInt_FromLong(v->ob_ival);
    return (PyObject *)v;
}
```

But this the furthest I can go by myself.

Where the actual value of an integer is stored inside an integer instance?

The main reason for this question is that I want to extend the `float` type with a `MyFloat` where I would like to refer to the value of the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual integer value is in `ob_ival`. In essence, `int_int` is simply taking the integer value from one `int` object and wrapping it in another object.

Not sure why you can't see the properties. If I run this, they show up for me, in both 2.7 and 3.4 versions:

```
x = 8
dir(x)
```

EDIT:
Too hard to explain in a comment, so adding to the answer.

You could easily subclass it like this:

```
class foo(int):
    def __getitem__(self):
        return self + 1

foo(8).__getitem__()
```

You could also use `super` to explicitly access the `int` object this way.

(You do realize that `__getitem__` is for use with keyed objects [dict-like, say] and hence normally gets a second argument specifying the key, right? And `int` and `float` are not keyed.)

Comment: Not really work for me in 2.7 `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ob_ival'`

Comment: Not sure what you're asking then. `ob_ival` is from the low-level object implementation (written in C). You can't access it from within the python script itself. But you don't need to. If `x` is an object of type `int` and you want the value, you simply reference `x` and it will be interpreted as an integer. If you want to convert it to float, say, use `float(x)`.

Comment: So if I want to implement a `__getitem__` that return the internal value + 1. How can I do it? (I know that nobody will need to do this)

Comment: Right, I was confused with the `__getitem__` which does not exist for an instance because it always returns itself. Thanks