# where does python store origin value for str

Tags: python, string, subclass

I'm new to python, and I have a simple question.

say I make a subclass of str to change everything into 'test':

```
class Mystr(str):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'test'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'test'

>>> mystr = Mystr(12345)
>>> print(mystr)
test
>>>
>>> print(mystr + 'test')
12345test
```

all I want is 'test', but 
where does python store the original value '12345' ? 
I can not find it anywhere.

```
>>> dir(mystr)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

after checking this, I actually find it in **getnewargs**

```
>>> mystr.__getnewargs__()
('12345',)
```

then I change this to :

```
class Mystr(str):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'test'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'test'
    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return 'test'

>>> mystr = Mystr(12345)
>>> print(mystr)
test
>>> mystr.__getnewargs__()
'test'
>>> print(mystr + 'test')
12345test
```

why is 12345 still there?
where does python store the original value '12345' ?

Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: You might be interested in the documentation for `tp_itemsize`.

Comment: As always, you can get the base class's behavior by calling base-class methods directly: `str.__str__(mystr)`

Comment: almost a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065862/where-is-stored-the-int-value-of-a-int-instance-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored in `self`. `self` is the object your method is attached to, that is, the string.

Comment: Where, specifically?  What is the attribute name?

Comment: It is not an attribute. It is the object itself.

Comment: haha...finally I realized this simple fact. ____str____ ___repr____  is only fake presentation of it, the value is itself, changing presentation doesn't change anything. now I know actually I should change the value by changing in the ____new____ method. thank you

Comment: It's possible to "fake" the string having a different value by overriding *all* the special methods, e.g. `__add__` and `__iter__` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass an argument to the class, the inbuilt function **__getnewargs__** local to the class is executed. The function then initializes all the variables  passed to the class as arguments and store them in a tuple.

Now, when you are trying to concatenate the class object, in your case **mystr**, with a string, the tuple containing ('12345',) returns its only argument '12345'  which is then concatenated with the string and printed as '12345test'.

If you try to print it like this way `print(mystr + ' anything')`, it will print '12345 anything'

For further info please look at 
[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5RPe.png)