# Why subclassing a str or int behaves differently from subclising a list or dict?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

When inheriting from string the value passed to `argument`is printed out:

```
class StringChild(str):

    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument

print(Child("text"))
```

Output:

```
text
```

Same thing when inheriting from int:

```
class IntChild(int):

    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument

print(IntChild(10))
```

Output:

```
10
```

However, when I inherit from a list or a dict I get an empty list or dict respectively:

```
class ListChild(list):

    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument

print(ListChild([1,2,3]))
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Why is there a different behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializing `self.argument = argument` does not *really* initialize the object itself (the list), it's just setting an arbitrary attribute called `argument`.

If you are using a half-decent IDE you should see a warning saying `Call to __init__ of super class is missing`.

If you do that you will get your list:

```
class ListChild(list):
    def __init__(self, argument):
        super().__init__(argument)
        # self.argument = argument

print(ListChild([1, 2, 3]))
# [1, 2, 3]
```

And you don't even need `self.argument`.

Now, you will see the same warning when subclassing `int` as well. The difference between `int` and `list` is that `int` is primitive and works a bit different. You don't even need to pass in `argument` to `super().__init__`. You are however required to pass it to `IntChild.__init__`:

```
class IntChild(int):
    def __init__(self, argument):
        super().__init__()

print(IntChild(3))
# 3
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065862/where-is-stored-the-int-value-of-a-int-instance-in-python) for more details about how `int` works.

Users are encouraged to subclass [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) and [`collections.UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) instead of `list` and `str` directly, however there is no `UserInt`.